# Java - Pair variable resets between consecutive for loop body executions

Tags: java, for-loop, nodelist

This is an excerpt from my project:

```
import javafx.util.Pair;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

private Pair<Element, Integer> findBestAlbumElement(Element recording) {
    Pair<Element, Integer> best = new Pair<>(null, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    NodeList list = recording.getElementsByTagName("release");

    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println((best.getKey() == null ? "null" : best.getKey().getTextContent()) + "; " + best.getValue());
        Element album = (Element) list.item(i);
        int mark = getAlbumAndYearMark(recording, album);

        if (mark > best.getValue()) best = new Pair<>(album, mark);
        System.out.println((best.getKey() == null ? "null" : best.getKey().getTextContent()) + "; " + best.getValue());
    }
    
    return best;
}
```

and I'm running into a strange problem in this piece of code. The variable `best` resets between loop iterations, as seen in the beginning of the printout to console:

> null; -2147483648
>
> Live USABootlegAlbumLive1990DE1990GermanyGermanyDE212CD2T.N.T255240; 6
>
> null; -2147483648
>
> ...

The first line is the first `System.out.println()`, the second line is the second one (where the variable `best` is properly set as expected) and the third line is the first one again (where the variable `best` seemingly just resets of its own accord).

I've tried to replicate the problem with the following code:

```
Pair<String, Integer> best = new Pair<>("", Integer.MIN_VALUE);
String[] strings = {"asdf", "fdsa", "dsaf"};
int[] marks = {1, 5, 3};

for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(best.getKey() + " " + best.getValue());
    if (marks[i] > best.getValue()) best = new Pair<>(strings[i], marks[i]);
    System.out.println(best.getKey() + " " + best.getValue());
}
```

which replaces the `NodeList` with a `String` array, but this code works as expected.

My problem is, I don't even know how to approach this issue. I don't know how to debug this further or even reproduce the problem in a smaller example, as I don't know how to create a valid `NodeList` (since it's an interface, so I can't just `new NodeList`).

I'm also at a bit of a loss, as it looks to me like the bug appears in a place where it shouldn't even be possible, since the only code that is supposed to execute between the two `println` calls is `i++` (not altering or even accessing `best` in any way). Am I wrong about this?

Does anyone have any idea what could be going on, or even how I would get closer to pinpointing the issue?

## EDIT

As per request, here's `getAlbumAndYearMark`, which uses the `jaudiotagger` library (apologies for the ugly long lined code, this is a fairly old project).

```
private Tag tag;

private int getAlbumAndYearMark(Element recording, Element album) {
    int mark = 0;
    
    if (album == null) return tag.hasField(FieldKey.YEAR) ? getYearMark(album) : 0;

    if (contains(album.getElementsByTagName("primary-type"), "Album")) mark += 2;
    else if (!contains(album.getElementsByTagName("secondary-type"), "Album")) return Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    Node title = album.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0);
    if (title != null && tag.hasField(FieldKey.ALBUM)) mark += title.getTextContent().equals(tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ALBUM)) ? 7 : -4;

    Node date = album.getElementsByTagName("date").item(0);
    if (date != null && tag.hasField(FieldKey.YEAR)) mark += date.getTextContent().equals(tag.getFirst(FieldKey.YEAR).trim()) ? 3 : -3;

    Node track = album.getElementsByTagName("number").item(0);
    if (track != null && tag.hasField(FieldKey.TRACK)) mark += track.getTextContent().equals(tag.getFirst(FieldKey.TRACK).trim()) ? 3 : -1;

    return mark;
}

private int getYearMark(Element element) {
    NodeList dates = element.getElementsByTagName("date");
    for (int i = 0; i < dates.getLength(); i++)
        if (dates.item(i).getTextContent().substring(0, 4).equals(tag.getFirst(FieldKey.YEAR))) return 7;
    return -7;
}

private static boolean contains(NodeList list, String string) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++)
        if (list.item(i).getTextContent().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(string)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

but I don't believe this method is the problem, as I still have the same issue if I replace `int mark = getAlbumYearMark(recording, album);` with `int mark = (int) (Math.random() * 10);`

Here's a (heavily trimmed) example XML file, printed directly from the program:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><metadata xmlns="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/mmd-2.0#" xmlns:ext="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/ext#-2.0" created="2018-02-16T02:07:28.816Z">
<recording-list count="72" offset="0">
  <recording ext:score="100" id="6e702972-00c2-4725-b3e5-60e85ef0de25">
    <title>T.N.T</title>
    <artist-credit>
      <name-credit>
        <artist id="66c662b6-6e2f-4930-8610-912e24c63ed1">
          <name>AC/DC</name>
        </artist>
      </name-credit>
    </artist-credit>
    <release-list>
      <release id="ddaa5690-df97-4bb2-b93d-396fe5fb49d5">
        <title>Live USA</title>
        <release-group id="6b1ace64-bf92-3c42-8a1f-aea6fa08edec" type="Live">
          <primary-type>Album</primary-type>
          <secondary-type-list>
            <secondary-type>Live</secondary-type>
          </secondary-type-list>
        </release-group>
        <date>1990</date>
        <country>DE</country>
        <release-event-list>
          <release-event>
            <date>1990</date>
            <area id="85752fda-13c4-31a3-bee5-0e5cb1f51dad">
              <name>Germany</name>
              <sort-name>Germany</sort-name>
              <iso-3166-1-code-list>
                <iso-3166-1-code>DE</iso-3166-1-code>
              </iso-3166-1-code-list>
            </area>
          </release-event>
        </release-event-list>
        <medium-list>
          <track-count>21</track-count>
          <medium>
            <position>2</position>
            <format>CD</format>
            <track-list count="11" offset="1">
              <track id="caadf3b8-4a44-34c6-b9dc-c9870c5d9bc0">
                <number>2</number>
              </track>
            </track-list>
          </medium>
        </medium-list>
      </release>
    </release-list>
  </recording>
</recording-list>
</metadata>
```

You can see an untrimmed example by querying the musicbrainz database directly, for example [this query](http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/recording?query=%22TNT%22%20AND%20artistname:%20%22AC/DC%22).

Comment: "not altering or even accessing best in any way". What about this `if (mark > best.getValue()) best = new Pair<>(album, mark);`?

Comment: Could you please provide signature and implementation of the `getAlbumAndYearMark` ? Also small xml file would be useful (just 2-3 records with your structure)

Comment: @IanMc nope, it's wrong. I'm just trying to reproduce the issue and `getTextContent` doesn't matter. You are confusing with invalid suggestions

Comment: @tsolakp, I was referring to the part between the 2nd and the 1st `println` call, not the code between the 1st and the 2nd.

Comment: @ADS, I've added the requested info, but I don't think that method is the problem, as I still have the same issue if I just use `Math.random()`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue yet. Do you have any threading?

Comment: Nope, no threading.

Comment: Are you sure `findBestAlbumElement` is not getting called more then once? The linked XML has more then one "release" element.

Comment: Ai ai ai. `findBestAlbumElement` was indeed getting called multiple times, once for each `<recording>`. I did consider that while debugging but I placed my `println` outside the loop over recordings, so it looked like it was only getting called once. I knew it was going to be something stupid like that. Thanks for your help, and feel free to downvote this question because I'm an idiot. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer (yet). I'm trying with next xml:

```
<root>
<release-list>
    <release id="ddaa5690-df97-4bb2-b93d-396fe5fb49d5">
        <title>Live USA</title>
        <date>1990</date>
        <country>DE</country>
    </release>
    <release id="qqqa5690-df97-4bb2-b93d-396fe5fb49d5">
        <title>German collections</title>
        <date>1991</date>
        <country>DE</country>
    </release>
</release-list>
<release-list>
    <release id="zzza5690-df97-4bb2-b93d-396fe5fb49d5">
        <title>Just USA</title>
        <date>1995</date>
        <country>US</country>
    </release>
</release-list>
<release-list>
    <release id="aaaa5690-df97-4bb2-b93d-396fe5fb49d5">
        <title>Anoother USA</title>
        <primary-type>Album</primary-type>
        <date>1999</date>
        <country>RUS</country>
    </release>
</release-list>
```

And I have no issues.  Could you please try with this xml?

Also I'm using both incremental mark like `return mockMark++;` and array-based mark like

```
private int getAlbumAndYearMark(Element recording, Element album) {
  int[] arr = {1,0,5,7,3,6,8,9,10};
  return arr[mockMark++];
}
```